# Как сохранить данные с сайта в csv-файл

Tags: javascript, csv

Всем привет. У меня очень тупой вопрос. Сразу скажу, что я не программист. Мне хотелось бы иметь скрипт, который берёт данные архива тиражей лотереи Гослото 5 из 36 с официального сайта (то есть выпавшие номера шаров)

https://www.stoloto.ru/5x36plus/archive

и записывает их в csv-файл. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Выполните в консоли браузера на вкладке с этим сайтом скрипт

```
$('.container.cleared:not(".sorted") > b')
   .map(function() {
      return this.innerText;
   })
   .toArray()
   .reduce(function(acc, current, position) {
      acc += position % 6 ? ',' : '\n';
      return acc += current;
   }, '');
```

и затем, то, что выведется в результате сохраните на компьютере в файле с расширением ".csv".

Это будет самым простым для вас вариантом, не требующим установки специальных утилит и т.д.